# The main page doesn´t appear in the pages menu

Tags: magento2

I noticed that in the pages menu we have a Home Page but when I click to see the page, It sends me a blank page, and if I click in the logo it shows me the main page that has images.

Can I edit that page? where can I do that? will I need to make the home page all over again from scratch?

Thanks !!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jONVI.jpg
this is the first page that show´s up when I go to the site

Comment: You are using magento's luma theme and sample data of magento. You need to update the blocks from widgets, static blocks and also from CMS home page.